# Why doesn't this Batch Program give an Output?

Tags: batch-file

I recently had an issue with one of my batch programs, it is basically an incompleted platformer: My code is work in progress and i got stuck with my attemp of collision detection. I have a matrix M, that i can access within an EnableDelayedExpansion block like this !M[%%a][%%d]!
The first time it works, but the second usage does not work anymore:
echo A!M[%xx%,%yy%]!B yields AB.

I would appreciate any hint.

Thanks in advance!

```
@echo off
::creating a new line variable for multi line strings
set NLM=^


:: Two empty lines are required here
::set up initial grid
set height=9
set width=14

for /l %%a in (0,1,9) do (
    for /l %%d in (0,1,14) do (
        set M[%%a][%%d]=.
    )
)

::create some vars at an initial value
set falling=0
set row=5
set turns=0
set x=8
set face=empty

:turn
set M[%row%][%x%]=^P    
::set wall position
set x2=4
set y2=6

set M[%y2%][%x2%]=^#

::display current grid
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "grid="
for /l %%a in (0,1,9) do (
    set line=!M[%%a][0]!
    for /l %%d in (1,1,14) do (
        set line=!line!!M[%%a][%%d]!
    )
    set grid=!grid! !NLM! !line!
)
cls
echo !grid!
endlocal

::prompt and make move
:: 4 = d
choice /c:wasd /n /m "" /t 1 /d s
set move=0
set /a xx=x
set /a yy=row

:move clearing Player
set M[%row%][%x%]=.
:: ^ this clears the characters trail so that there is no trail left behind after
:: moves, even when blocked. But at the start of grid Player is drawn again.

if %errorlevel%==4 ( if %x% LSS %width% ( set face=right 
set /a xx=x+1) else ( set face=empty))
::if %errorlevel%==3 ( if %row% LSS %height% ( set face=down 
::set /a move=0) else ( set face=empty))
if %errorlevel%==2 ( if %x% GTR 0 ( set face=left 
set /a xx=x-1) else ( set face=empty))
if %errorlevel%==1 ( if %row% GTR 0 ( set face=up 
set /a move=1) else ( set face=empty))


::falling!
set /a yy=yy-move

if %move%==0 (
    set /a falling+=1        
    set face=down
) else (
    set falling=0
)

set /a yy=yy+falling
::collision tests
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
::echo !M[%xx%,%yy%]! > tmp.var
echo A!M[%xx%,%yy%]!B
endlocal
::set /P var1="" < tmp.var
::if %var1%==# (
::    set face=empty
::)


::now the actual movements
::if %face%==right set /a x+=1
::if %face%==left set /a x-=1
::if %face%==up set /a row=yy
::if %face%==down set /a row=yy
set /a x=xx
set /a row=yy
::increment turns, return to top
set /a turns+=1
goto :turn
```

Comment: What website did you get this code from?  Some of it looks very familiar to me.

Comment: @Squashman - The commenting style, multidimensional array format, and starting loops on `%%a` reminds me of my own code.

Comment: And to try and get more info, does `!M[%xx%][%yy%]!` return results?

Comment: Alter `echo A!M[%xx%,%yy%]!B` to `echo A!M[%xx%,%yy%]!B %xx% %yy%&pause` and debug from there.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I will try to get into details. This is the code that i want to use:
`::collision tests`
`setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`
`echo !M[%xx%,%yy%]! > tmp.var`
`endlocal`
`set /P var1="" < tmp.var`
`if %var1%==# (`
`set face=empty`
`)`

As this does not work i add a debugging line:
`echo A!M[%xx%,%yy%]!B%xx%C%yy%D&pause`
The output of this line is like this
AB8C8D
So, xx and yy have values, but i can not get the value of M[x,y].